# Evaluate $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x\tan x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}-1}$ Without Lhopital

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

> $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x\tan x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}-1}$$

Tried using $\tan x\approx x$ and $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\tan x}{x}=1$

$$
\begin{align} \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x\tan x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}-1}\approx\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}-1}  &=\lim_{x\to 0}-\left(-\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}-1}\right)\\  &=\lim_{x\to 0}-\left(\frac{1-x^2-1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}-1}\right)\end{align}$$

Comment: And what happened when you tried that, and what else have you tried?

Comment: Hint: rationalize the denominator.

Comment: At your level of rep, you need to know that trig functions in mathjax are preceded by a backward slash: $\tan x$, and to format correctly, you cannot run-on tanx.  You literally need `\tan x`. I edited you post for you, but I won't do so again; after 10K rep, you ought to know better.

Comment: Expand both numerator and denominator in power series - need only first non-zero term for each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the conjugate and then use $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\tan x}{x}=1$,

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x\tan x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}-1}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x\tan x (\sqrt{1-x^2}+1)}{-x^2} $$
$$=-\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\tan x}x  (\sqrt{1-x^2}+1)= -2$$

Answer (score 1):

Assumin that you could like more than the limit itself, consider the composition of Taylor series
$$\sqrt{1-x^2}=1-\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^4}{8}+O\left(x^6\right)$$
$$\sqrt{1-x^2}-1=-\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^4}{8}+O\left(x^6\right)$$
$$x\frac{\tan (x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}-1}=x\frac{x+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{2 x^5}{15}+O\left(x^7\right) } {-\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^4}{8}+O\left(x^6\right) }$$ Now, long division to get
$$\frac{x\tan (x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}-1}=-2-\frac{x^2}{6}+O\left(x^4\right)$$

For the fun of it, try for $x=\frac \pi 6$ whch is quite far away from $0$. The exact value is 
$$\frac{\pi }{\sqrt{3} \left(\sqrt{36-\pi ^2}-6\right)}\approx -2.042$$ while the series would give
$$-2-\frac{\pi ^2}{216}\approx -2.046$$

Answer (score 0):

By using $x=\sin 2u$ we obtain $$L{=\lim_{u\to 0}{\sin 2u\cdot \tan(\sin 2u)\over \cos 2u-1}\\=\lim_{u\to 0}{2\sin u\cos u\cdot \tan(\sin 2u)\over -2\sin^2u}\\=-\lim_{u\to 0}{\tan (\sin 2u)\over \sin u}\\=-2}$$since $\tan w\approx w$ and $\sin u\approx u$ for $|u|<<1$.

Comment: How did you arrive to $\frac{\tan (\sin 2u)}{\sin u}$?

Comment: I simplified a $\sin u$ from both the numerator and denominator and substituted $0$ in $\cos u$ to cancel it out.

Answer (score -1):

For small u, $\ \sqrt{1-u} \approx 1-\frac{1}{2}u$.

When $x$ is small, so is $x^2$, thus the following approximation is also valid:

$\ \sqrt{1-x^2} \approx 1-\frac{1}{2}x^2$

Also using $\tan x\approx x$, and forgetting rigour (lol), we get:

$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x\tan x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}-1} = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^2}{1-1/2 (x^2)-1} = -2$

Comment: I'm sure you can make this more rigorous with Taylor series or something, but in general is this method fine? It gets the right answer... I'm not sure when it's appropriate to use certain approximations like this in limits.